# Traying to replace data in JSON with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I trying to replace key value in JSON using PHP and AJAX, and JavaScript to display value.

my JSON database that schuold be change:

```
    "answer01count": "1",
    "answer02count": "2",
    "answer03count": "3",
    "answer04count": "5",
    "answer05count": "10"
```

my Ajax code:

```
ans = $("input[name=answear]:checked").val();
$("#result").click(function(){
    $("progress").show();
var x = json.Endokrynologia[val];
if(ans==x.answear01){
    count = x.answear01count;
}
if(ans==x.answer02){
    count = x.answer02count;
}
if(ans==x.answer03){
    count = x.answer03count;
}
if(ans==x.answer04){
    count = x.answer04count;
}
if(ans==x.answer05){
    count = x.answer05count;
}

post_data = { $choice : count };        
     $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                data: post_data,
                url: 'count.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    result = data;
                    alert(result)
                }
    });
});
```

php code:

```
<?php
$count = $_POST['$choice']; 
$jsonString = file_get_contents('question.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

if($data[0]['answer01count'] == $count){
    $data[0]['answer01count'] = $count+1;
}
if($data[0]['answer02count'] == $count){
    $data[0]['answer02count'] = $count+1;
}
if($data[0]['answer03count'] == $count){
    $data[0]['answer03count'] = $count+1;
}
if($data[0]['answer04count'] == $count){
    $data[0]['answer04count'] = $count+1;
}
if($data[0]['answer05count'] == $count){
    $data[0]['answer05count'] = $count+1;
}

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('question.json', $newJsonString);
?>
```

Any idea what i did wrong?! I don't have any errors, but also i don't have expecting output.

UPDATE:
change = for ==

My json file is decode and encode correctly, but still value of a key won't change.

Comment: `$data[0]['answear01count'] = $count`  Single `=` in PHP is assignment, no?

Comment: all php file i inside my question, so its all you see. just trying that for 1st question if it will works i will go for loop.

Comment: I know.  I'm saying you have a typo.  You are doing an assignment expression in your ifs, rather than an equality (`==`) check

Comment: going to edit my question, adding == change little but not everything.

Comment: How is this all wired up? the JSON is in a json file, your php is altering the json file, which is fine, the ajax, I assume, is accessing the json file. Or is it? It's pointing to a php file... could you describe or indicate the workflow here?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values in your php if statements:

```
if($data[0]['answear05count'] = $count){
  $data[0]['answear05count'] = $count+1;
}
```

Should be replaced by:

```
if($data[0]['answear05count'] == $count){
  $data[0]['answear05count'] = $count+1;
}
```

Do the  same for all other if statements

Comment: oo ye.. double equal forgett that.. will check :D

Comment: ok, so, it decode my json file and encode it, but not change any value..

Comment: Another problem: answear05count doesn't exist, replace it by answer05count. Applies to everything else

Comment: forgot to edit that in question, but that was already done, that's not changing the value

Comment: not for me, i add echo $count for easy check, and everytime i select answer5 have same value = 10, when it schould be 11, after relod and select again 12 and etc...

Comment: Also please udate your json code: add opening ({) and closing (}) brackets